# HidesBottomBarOnPush iOS10 safe area pinning issue

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios10, uitabbar, safearealayoutguide

I'm having an issue with the safe area on iOS 10 where I trigger a segue to a view controller with `hidesBottomBarOnPush` enabled. The content which is pinned to the bottom safe area on this view controller starts off above the tabs then jumps to the bottom once the view has fully loaded.

How do I avoid this behaviour on iOS 10? Pinning to superview is not an option as iPhone X support is required.

[image]

Constraints on the label:

[image]

Comment: Set bottom constraint of "Pinned To Bottom" to Safe Area.

Comment: @phani it is already pinned to the bottom of the safe area

Answer (score 0):

Pinning to superview, bind to the attribute, like this

```
@interface YourViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint;

@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat bottomValue = 0.0f; // your value
    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.layoutMargins;
    CGFloat bottomInset = edgeInsets.bottom;
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = - bottomInset - bottomValue;
}

@end
```